# Tkinter button only works when I close the button window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to play a game of wae, activated by a button. The button shows and clicks but does nothing. Once I close the button window the program executes and runs the game. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
from PythonLabs.IterationLab import *
from random import *
from enum import Enum 
from enum import IntEnum 
from tkinter import * 



        from tkinter import *
        from tkinter import ttk


        class PlayingCard:
            def __init__(self, card_value, card_suit):
                self.card = card_value
                self.suit = card_suit


        def create_deck():
            for suit in Suit :
                for card in Card:
                    full_deck.append(PlayingCard(Card(card), Suit(suit)))
            return full_deck

        def deal_war():
            while(len(partial_deck) > 0):
                player1_cards.append(draw_card(partial_deck))
                player2_cards.append(draw_card(partial_deck))
                full_deck = []

        def click():
            deal_war()


        def draw_card(deck):
            rand_card = randint(0,len(deck) -1)
            return deck.pop(rand_card)

        window = Tk()
        button = Button(window, text='Draw')
        button.config(command=click, padx=20, pady=20)
        button.pack()

        partial_deck = []
        player1_cards = []
        player2_cards = []

        window.mainloop()
       

        class Card(IntEnum):
            TWO = 2
            THREE = 3
            FOUR = 4
            FIVE = 5
            SIX = 6
            SEVEN = 7
            EIGHT = 8
            NINE = 9
            TEN = 10
            JACK = 11
            QUEEN = 12
            KING = 13
            ACE = 14

        class Suit(Enum):
            SPADES = 'spades'
            CLUBS = 'clubs'
            HEARTS = 'hearts'
            DIAMONDS = 'diamonds'


        full_deck = []
        partial_deck = []
        player1_cards = []
        player2_cards = []


        create_deck()
        partial_deck = list(full_deck)
        deal_war()

        for i in range(0, len(player1_cards)):
            if (player1_cards[i].card > player2_cards[i].card):
                print("Player 1 wins with:", player1_cards[i].card)
                print("Player 2 loses  with:", player2_cards[i].card)
            if (player1_cards[i].card < player2_cards[i].card):
                print("Player 2 wins with:", player2_cards[i].card)
                print("Player 1 loses  with:", player1_cards[i].card)
            else:
                print("WAR!")
```

Comment: Why do you need `def click():`? Why not just use `button = Button(window, text='Draw', command=deal_war)`?

Comment: Please try to consolidate that code into a single block. Breaking it all apart makes it difficult for us to run it.

Comment: I am having issues in consolidating it into one block, I get an error that I need more information than just the code.

Comment: I will try that Rory

Answer (score 2):

#### Answering Your Direct Question

Your issue is where you have your 'window.mainloop()' line.

Python is going to run the file from top to bottom, and when it hits that line it waits for the mainloop to end before continuing.

I'd recommend moving this block of code into a function that your button calls.

```py
full_deck = []
partial_deck = []
player1_cards = []
player2_cards = []


create_deck()
partial_deck = list(full_deck)
deal_war()

for i in range(0, len(player1_cards)):
    if (player1_cards[i].card > player2_cards[i].card):
        print("Player 1 wins with:", player1_cards[i].card)
        print("Player 2 loses  with:", player2_cards[i].card)
    if (player1_cards[i].card < player2_cards[i].card):
        print("Player 2 wins with:", player2_cards[i].card)
        print("Player 1 loses  with:", player1_cards[i].card)
    else:
        print("WAR!")
```

#### Explaining other issues since you said your new to python

You're missing a few imports that you are trying to use

```py
from enum import IntEnum, Enum
from random import randint
```

Your code structure also lends itself to a lot of state issues. I would recommend wrapping your code into objects.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from enum import IntEnum, Enum
from random import randint

class PlayingCard:
    def __init__( self, card_value, card_suit ):
        self.card = card_value
        self.suit = card_suit

class Card(IntEnum):
        TWO = 2
        THREE = 3
        FOUR = 4
        FIVE = 5
        SIX = 6
        SEVEN = 7
        EIGHT = 8
        NINE = 9
        TEN = 10
        JACK = 11
        QUEEN = 12
        KING = 13
        ACE = 14

class Suit(Enum):
    SPADES = 'spades'
    CLUBS = 'clubs'
    HEARTS = 'hearts'
    DIAMONDS = 'diamonds'

class War:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.partial_deck = []
        self.player1_cards = []
        self.player2_cards = []

        self.full_deck = []
        self.partial_deck = []
        self.player1_cards = []
        self.player2_cards = []

    def create_deck( self ):
        for suit in Suit :
            for card in Card:
                self.full_deck.append(PlayingCard(Card(card), Suit(suit)))
        return self.full_deck

    def deal_war( self ):
        while(len(self.partial_deck) > 0):
            self.player1_cards.append(self.draw_card(self.partial_deck))
            self.player2_cards.append(self.draw_card(self.partial_deck))
            full_deck = []

    def draw_card( self, deck ):
        rand_card = randint(0,len(deck) -1)
        return deck.pop(rand_card)

    def start( self ):
        window = Tk()
        button = Button(window, text='Draw')
        button.config(command=lambda:self.run(), padx=20, pady=20)
        button.pack()
        window.mainloop()

    def run( self ):
        self.create_deck()
        self.partial_deck = list(self.full_deck)
        self.deal_war()

        for i in range(0, len(self.player1_cards)):
            if (self.player1_cards[i].card > self.player2_cards[i].card):
                print("Player 1 wins with:", self.player1_cards[i].card)
                print("Player 2 loses  with:", self.player2_cards[i].card)
            if (self.player1_cards[i].card < self.player2_cards[i].card):
                print("Player 2 wins with:", self.player2_cards[i].card)
                print("Player 1 loses  with:", self.player1_cards[i].card)
            else:
                print("WAR!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = War()
    game.start()
```

Lastly you'll notice my use of `if __name__ == '__main__':`
This is to ensure the file doesn't run when you import it. In case you want to reuse any of these classes in another file.

Comment: If you do not have the reputation to answer a question, asking a question in the answer section could lead to a lowering of your reputation score. The answer section is strictly for answers.

Comment: That is the way it is structured. when I move the main.loop to the end it wont run. I am using idle shell if that makes any difference. I am very new to this .

Comment: Hey Jacob, Don't stress about the -1s. Writing "proper" questions on here can be difficult. I'll try and help you out.
In addition to my answer to your question I think you missing some imports.
1.)from enum import IntEnum, Enum
2.)from random import randint

Comment: @BryanOakley I take that risk in hopes that after my question is answered I can edit my question to an answer, and others will up vote that answer. Its unfortunate that the ability to ask questions is behind a rep wall. That should be a default feature.

Comment: @Jacobrm84 I've editing my answer to help you out. Send me an @ if you have any questions.